# Increase TensorFlow Lite speed on Android

Tags: android, image, performance, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

**How fast can I expect a 1 million parameter model to run on an Android phone?**

I've made several models with Keras for image enhancement running on Android with TFLite, but they are very slow. Right now one 256x256 image is processed in ~0.5 seconds on a flagship smartphone. Ideally I'd like it to run 30 FPS in FullHD, so it's several hundred times slower than desired.

The models I've tried now are almost exclusively made with convolution layers and have around one million parameters. Is this the speed I can expect from models this size? I feels like I'm doing something wrong. I don't expect to meet my ideal goal of 30 FPS, but how much faster could I it be?

Comment: The Answer is Difficult. FPS is depends on Hardware Requirements and .tflite model  Performance. Have you Tried GPU Delegate..!!

Comment: +1 on trying the delegates and quantizing the model. There are a few other tips here: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/best_practices